# How to use SVN-commit in powershell

Tags: powershell, svn

I would like to use SVN commands in my PowerShell script.

I know I need to declare the SVN executable as a variable, but afterwards I want to commit a file which I have declared as a variable and the commit message I would like to give is specified in a file.

```
$svnExe = "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe"
$myFile = "C:\xx\file.txt"
$commitMsg = "C:\xx\msg.txt"
```

`$myFile` is already a versioned file, `$commitMsg` is not and will also not be a versioned file.

From command-line this works:

```
svn commit -F C:\xx\msg.txt C:\xx\file.txt
```

But how would I do this using PowerShell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Svn works the same way in PowerShell as it does in a Command Prompt. If you define a variable with the full path to the executable you need to run it via the [call operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) (`&`), though, because otherwise PowerShell would simply echo the string and be confused about the rest of the commandline.

```
$svn = 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe'
$myFile = 'C:\xx\file.txt'
$commitMsg = 'C:\xx\msg.txt'

& $svn commit -F $commitMsg $myFile
```

If you add the Svn directory to your path environment variable you can just invoke the executable directly:

```
$env:PATH += ';C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin'

...

svn.exe commit -F $commitMsg $myFile
```

Another option would be to define an alias for the executable:

```
New-Alias -Name svn -Value 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe'

...

svn commit -F $commitMsg $myFile
```

Comment: I tried the first suggestion you made. And find out that it need to be:
$svnExe = 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe'
$myFile = 'C:\xx\file.txt'
$commitMsg = 'C:\xx\msg.txt'

& $svnExe commit -F $commitMsg $myFile


But afterwards I got the following problem:
svn: E205008: Log message contains a zero byte
At line:6 char:2
+ & <<<<  $svnExe commit -F $commitMsg $myFile
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (svn: E205008: L...ins a zero byte:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: Any idea how I solve the <svn: E205008: Log message contains a zero byte> issue?

Comment: @tommy2479 You saved `msg.txt` in Unicode format. Save the file in ANSI format and the error will disappear.

Comment: this really helped me out thnx!