# How can I use unary operator in Powershell expression as parameter

Tags: powershell

I'm doing a Powershell script which will call a svn command to relocate a repo. The command will look like this:

```
$newurl = "https://pathtonewurl"
Invoke-Expression -Command "svn relocate $newurl --username 'user' --password 'password'"
```

When running, I get: Missing expression after unary operator `'--'`.
How can I use `--parameter` in an expression ?

Comment: You should now use `Invoke-Expression` for such a purpose. Instead you can use the stop parsing symbol (--%) of PowerShell. Here you can read more: [Stop Parsing on ss64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/stop-parsing.html) and [About Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.1#argument-mode)

Answer (score 1):

Since `svn` isn't a powershell command, use Start-Process instead:

```
Start-Process svn -ArgumentList "relocate $newurl --username 'user' --password 'password'"
```

Or try the call operator `&`: [How to use SVN-commit in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473520/how-to-use-svn-commit-in-powershell/43473976)